# Programa para gerenciar banco de dados MySQL no Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows

Alguém sabe me informar algum programa para gerenciar banco de dados [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) no Windows?

No Mac eu uso um chamado [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/), porém ele é somente para Mac.

Alguém conhece algum parecido?

Comment: Acredito que essa pergunta seja baseada em opniões, na minha opnião.

Answer (score 7):

Existe uma ampla lista se softwares que podem ser utilizados para este fim, tanto possíveis de serem instalados na máquina quanto instalados no servidor possibilitando o gerenciamento do seu banco de dados a partir de qualquer [so](/questions/tagged/so).

**Instalados na maquina:**
Dentre todos os que eu conheço os que eu recomendo são:
 - [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) Produzido e mantido pela [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) que é mantenedora do [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)
 - [DBvis](http://www.dbvis.com/) um gerenciador universal de bancos de dados. Gerencia de forma eficiente os `SGBDs` mais comuns no mercado

**Instalado no Servidor:**
o [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) é um gerenciador do [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) feito em [php](/questions/tagged/php) e é bem comum de ser visto em hospedagens e também é facilmente instalado em seu ambiente [php](/questions/tagged/php) (se existir, claro).

Answer (score 6):

Um dos mais usados é o [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) .

Eu uso muito também o [Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: Vou ver esse Workbench, gostaria de algum sem ser o phpmyadmin.

Comment: Então vai no wb que ele é muito bom mesmo e tem muitos recursos. Vale a pena testar, além de ser free.

Comment: O mais legal do WorkBench é a capacidade de criar diagramas visualmente e então criar o banco de dados real a partir dele. Aliás, não é só criar, mas você consegue fazer um `diff` cada vez que alterar o diagrama para atualizar seu banco de dados.

Answer (score 4):

Eu utilizo o [Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) e o [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/).

O navicat faz conexões com vários tipos de bancos de dados (MySQL, MSSQL, Postgre, Oracle e SQLite) além de ter várias funções bastante úteis, como transferência entre bancos de dados e uma interface muito boa. Recomendo mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Tem o [MySQL Workbeanch](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) desenvolvido pela Oracle. Acredito que seja o mais utilizado, visto que a Oracle é detentora do MySQL. Este possui diversos recursos gráficos. Você pode, por exemplo, desenhar o MER e depois exportar para sql. Também é possível fazer engenharia reversa em um sql e gerar o MER (e vice-versa), além de suportar querys.

Conheço também o [SQLYog](https://www.webyog.com/product/downloads) que é bastante robusto e o [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php) que roda dentro do servidor