# Alternativa ao PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Alguém sabe me informar um gerenciador de banco de dados em que eu possa montar queries mais complexas sem ter que digitar a query? Apenas clicando onde quero fazer um SELECT por exemplo?

Preciso fazer várias queries que envolvem um SELECT em várias tabelas ao mesmo tempo utilizando INNER JOIN porém meu conhecimento em SQL é mínimo. O que eu queria era poder clicar nas colunas das tabelas em que quero fazer o select e o aplicativo montar a query para mim, coisa que não tenho no PhpMyAdmin que estou usando atualmente.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9057/programa-para-gerenciar-banco-de-dados-mysql-no-windows talvez ajude

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Programa para gerenciar banco de dados MySQL no Windows?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9057/programa-para-gerenciar-banco-de-dados-mysql-no-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia!

Tente usar o MySQL Workbench. É uma boa opção para quem quer sair do PHPMyAdmin.
Espero ter ajudado.